# How search for HTML elements in StreamReader or String

Tags: c#, .net, web-crawler

I've been searching a simple web crawler, and i need search an elements inside my StreamBuilder or string. Example, i need get all content inside an div with id "bodyDiv". Which tool helper me with this?

```
private static string GetPage(string url)

        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.UserAgent = "Simple crawler";    
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return htmlText;

        }
```

Comment: Try http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: For reading HTML in .NET, the recommended library is the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlText);

var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='bodyDiv']");
if(div!=null)
{
    var yourtext = div.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Dear sir, I've to write all data from this <div class="filter-grey-bar"> The what should be code for the SelectSingleNode

Comment: Sir, How can I use this code in case if <div class="xyz"> appears multiple time in our page? Please help me